# Test automation with Puppet?

Tags: java, automated-tests, puppet, performance-testing, load-testing

Is it possible to automate tests on a server using puppet ? I have done some research but cannot find any accurate resources. if its possible, can it be done without the puppet enterprise ?

I am trying to test how much load a software (java server) can handle under different configurations, is it possible to do this using puppet?

If someone can direct me to a good source that'll help a lot.

Thank You.

Comment: try `rspec` - http://rspec-puppet.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of testing are you after for this

> possible to automate tests on a server using puppet ?

As you know [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) is about managing your (test) infrastructure, like getting the required this test environment to the desired state (fixtures). My guess is that you need to consider one of the most used [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) servers - [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo). They all can support your testing process. As example I've used Jenkins and remote physical machine to run
API tests on it, and TeamCity and remote VM for my Selenium grid server.

UPDATE:

For your performance testing you can use some tool like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), framework like [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) *or* your own framework implementation with some client like [google-http-java-client](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client). And Puppet to tune this java server

> under different configurations

per test execution.

Comment: I am trying to test how much load a software (java server) can handle under different configurations, is it possible to do this using puppet?

Comment: ok. one more thing, can I run something like apache bench or JMeter using puppet ?

Comment: Well actually you can run anything that is runable, like *.exe* files. To pass them params you'll need need to implement your own executable that starts the required one and pass those. The question is - do you really need to ?!? Just use the tools designed for such actions - CI servers.

Comment: Thank You for your answer , yh better go with those tools :)